# Is there a way to make bash job control quiet?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, parallel-processing

Bash is quite verbose when running jobs in the background:

```
$ echo toto&
toto
[1] 15922
[1]+  Done                    echo toto
```

Since I'm trying to run jobs in parallel and use the output, I'd like to find a way to silence bash. Is there a way to remove this superfluous output?

Comment: This is particularly annoying when my dotfile has some file cleanup logic that I don't want to see every time I start a new shell session!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use parentheses to run a background command in a subshell, and that will silence the job control messages. For example:

```
(sleep 10 & )
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing (see comments on the accepted answer).

Comment: @CodeGnome I actually didn't understand the original answer until I Googled "parentheses in bash" on a hunch, and discovered it was the parens specifically that made it a subshell. (Before that, I'd thought it was the ampersand that made it a subshell.)

Comment: @mklement0 While your suggestion is technically correct, it doesn't answer the question.  The construct { command & } 2>/dev/null hides the initial job control message, but there is no way to suppress the '[1]- Done' message when the sleep completed.

Comment: @Dave: Thanks for making me dig deeper. Let me summarize differently: `(sleep 10 &)` conveniently silences both creation and termination messages, but you lose control of the background job.
To avoid that, use `{ sleep 10 & } 2>/dev/null` to silence the _creation_ message, and use either `wait` or `kill` analogously to silence the _termination_ message (which may not always be an option).
Alternatively, `set +m` can be used to categorically silence termination messages, which, however, has many potentially unwanted side effects. My answer (hopefully) has the full story.

Comment: the `()` notation spawns a subshell which then forks another one `&`, that's not optimal

Comment: This feels so much cleaner when running my dotfile. Thanks.

Answer (score 59):

<sup>Note: The following applies to *interactive* Bash sessions. In *scripts*, job-control messages are *never* printed.</sup>

There are **2 basic scenarios** for **silencing Bash's job-control messages**:

---

#### Launch-and-forget:

[CodeGnome's helpful answer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11111042/45375) suggests **enclosing the background command in a simple subshell** - e.g, `(sleep 10 &)` - which effectively silences job-control messages - both on job *creation* and on job *termination*.

This has an **important side effect**:

- **By using control operator `&` *inside* the subshell, you *lose control of the background job*** - `jobs` won't list it, and neither `%%` (the spec. (ID) of the most recently launched job) nor `$!` (the PID of the (last) process launched (as part of) the most recent job) will reflect it.<sup>[1]</sup>

For **launch-and-forget scenarios, this is *not* a problem**:

- You just fire off the background job,
- and you let it finish on its own (and you trust that it runs correctly).

<sup>[1] Conceivably, you could go looking for the process yourself, by searching running processes for ones matching its command line, but that is cumbersome and not easy to make robust.</sup>

---

#### Launch-and-control-later:

If you want to **remain in control of the job**, so that you can later:

- **kill it**, if need be.
- **synchronously wait** (at some later point) for its completion,

a different approach is needed:

- Silencing the *creation* job-control messages is handled below, but in order to  **silence the *termination* job-control messages *categorically***, you must **turn the job-control shell option OFF**:

  - `set +m` (`set -m` turns it back on)
  - **Caveat**: This is a **global setting** that has a number of **important side effects**, notably:

    - Stdin for background commands is then `/dev/null` rather than the current shell's.
    - The keyboard shortcuts for suspending (<kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>) and delay-suspending (<kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd>) a foreground command are disabled.
    - For the full story, see [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) and (case-insensitively) search for occurrences of "job control".
- To **silence the *creation* job-control messages**, enclose the background command in a **group command** and redirect the latter's stderr output to `/dev/null`

  ```
  { sleep 5 & } 2>/dev/null
  ```

The following example shows how to quietly launch a background job while retaining control of the job in principle.

```
$ set +m; { sleep 5 & } 2>/dev/null # turn job-control option off and launch quietly
$ jobs # shows the job just launched; it will complete quietly due to set +m
```

**If you do *not* want to turn off the job-control option (`set +m`), the only way to silence the *termination* job-control message is to either `kill` the job or `wait` for it:**

Caveat: There are *two edge cases* where this technique still produces output:

- If the background command tries to read from stdin *right away*.
- If the background command terminates *right away*.

To launch the job quietly (as above, but without `set +m`):

```
$ { sleep 5 & } 2>/dev/null
```

To `wait` for it quietly:

```
$ wait %% 2>/dev/null    # use of %% is optional here
```

To `kill` it quietly:

```
{ kill %% && wait; } 2>/dev/null
```

The additional `wait` is necessary to make the termination job-control message that is normally displayed *asynchronously* by Bash (at the time of actual process termination, shortly after the kill) a *synchronous* output from `wait`, which then allows silencing.

But, as stated, if the job completes *by itself*, a job-control message will still be displayed.

Comment: Note there is an additional caveat to the group command technique: standard error output from the command itself is suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a dummy script:

quiet.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
"$@" &
```

then call it, passing your command to it as an argument:

```
./quiet.sh echo toto
```

You may need to play with quotes depending on your input.

Comment: clever, but doesn't seem to work with some bash constructs. Example: quiet.sh "[ -e quiet.sh ] || echo prout"

Comment: `"$@"` should **definitely** be quoted. This won't work most of the time - only for executing single simple commands. You may as well just use `bash -c 'cmds'`, or `bash -s <<"EOF"`

Comment: @ormaaj Quoting "$@" is even worse, but "bash -c" seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Even better, using () to run in a subshell works: (echo toto&)

Comment: You lose job control that way. The forked process becomes a child of init. Running a separate script doesn't have that problem if you're really trying to manage parallel things, but it sounds like that isn't actually important to you.

Comment: I'm just trying to run things in parallel, while retaining the output. I should have said so in the question.

Comment: @static_rtti, "worse" is not quite the right way to describe it. Unquoted `$@` behaves the same as unquoted `$*`, with all the same bugs. You don't want those bugs.

Comment: Aside from the (easily fixable) quoting issue, this (inherently) only works with a single, simple command without redirections; e.g., you can't pass a pipeline or multiple commands that way.
The `(echo toto &)` approach is both much simpler and more flexible. Either way, though, as @ormaaj points out, you lose control of the job.

Answer (score 1):

Interactively, no. It will always display job status. You can influence when the status is shown using `set -b`.

There's nothing preventing you from using the output of your commands (via pipes, or storing it variables, etc). The job status is sent to the controlling terminal by the shell and doesn't mix with other I/O. If you're doing something complex with jobs, the solution is to write a separate script.

The job messages are only really a problem if you have, say, functions in your bashrc which make use of job control which you want to have direct access to your interactive environment. Unfortunately there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the simplest way to achieve this, which I have used on many occasions is as follows:

```
exec {oldfd2}<&2 # copy/dup stderr
exec 2<&- # tell stderr to zip it
sleep 3 &
sleep3bgpid=$!
someotherbgcmd 2>&$oldfd2 & 
#route stderr of this job to orig stderr
otherbgcmdpid=$!
# restore things as they were...
exec 2<&$oldfd2 # restore stderr
exec {oldfd2}>&- # close dup'ed fd
unset oldfd2 # keep env clean
...
unset sleep3bgpid othercmdbgpid
```

Be careful when using set +/-m, I run many tasks without a tty in the session, see echo $-, where assuming that job control is present is incorrect. In a normal interactive session those flags are: himBHs, however, in a remote tty'less session they are hiBHs.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a lot of the above as an inspiration, I wrote a `starter` and `monitor` function pair that allow me to start a long running process, monitor it, and get its return code, all without making changes to job control (no `set +m`) and without having the shell's "helpful" messages written to the screen. I also still get output and error messages from the long running command, without complex redirection.

Motivation: I needed this for a complicated set of scripts I am writing, wherein I want to control what is displayed to the user while retaining as much information about the long running command as possible.

The two-part solution was 1) to use not one but two levels of backgrounding and 2) used a shared file to capture PID and return code information. Note that a FIFO could work just as well, I just tried the file route first and it worked well enough.

A fairly concise bit of demo code for this follows below; this code calls an external; `longRunner.bash`, which is just a long sleep (the first argument, `5` in this case, is the time longRunner.bash sleeps) with an arbitrary exit code (the second argument, 121 in this case). Note that this demo code has minimal-to-no error checking, really should have better quoting, etc. This really was just enough to prove the point to myself.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -u

pidSleep=.1
monitorSleep=1
rcSleep=.1

starter () {
    [[ $# -lt 2 ]] && { echo $0 needs a monitor file and a command; exit 1; }
    ${@:2} &
    echo $! > $reapFile
    printf "This is the first error message from starter\n" >&2
    wait -f $!
    echo $? > $reapFile
    printf "This is the second error message from starter\n" >&2
}

monitor () {
    [[ $# -ne 1 ]] && { echo $0 needs a monitor file; exit 1; }
    local reapFile=$1
    local startTime=$SECONDS
    # sleep, briefly, so that starter has time to write the PID
    sleep $pidSleep
    read < $reapFile
    local pid=$REPLY
    [[ -z $pid ]] && { echo uhoh; exit 1; }
    while ps $pid >& /dev/null; do
        printf "\r$pid still running after $(($SECONDS - $startTime))" >&2
        sleep $monitorSleep
    done
    # sleep again, so that starter can write the result code
    sleep $rcSleep
    read < $reapFile
    printf "\rreturn code was $REPLY\n" >&2
}

reapFile=$(mktemp)
someErrorFile=$(mktemp)
# start starter in the background in a subshell so that the
# "helpful" job control messages from bash are suppressed
( starter ${reapFile} ./longRunner.bash 5 121 2> $someErrorFile & )
monitor ${reapFile}
cat $someErrorFile
rm $someErrorFile
rm $reapFile
exit
```

Rather than using `sleep <someFractionOfASecond>` to solve the race problem, this could use something along the lines of

```
while [[ ! -s $reapFile ]]; do continue; done
read $reapFile
```

for a busy spin, but this could have its own complications. It may be possible to use a FIFO with blocking reads to accomplish the same results more efficiently. Both alternatives are left as exercises for the reader. :->

Answer (score -5):

One solution (in bash anyway) is to route all the output to /dev/null

```
    echo 'hello world' > /dev/null &
```

The above will not give you any output other than the id for the bg process.

Comment: This suppresses nothing but the command's output itself - "the id for the bg process" is precisely the job-control message that the OP wants to silence.