# how to suppress the reporting output from background tasks?

Tags: bash

to clarify, by reporting output, here i mean the ones start with `[1]`:

```
$ echo hello world >&2 &
[1] 11714
hello world
[1]+  Done                    echo hello world 1>&2
```

which means i want `hello world` to be output.

i did a lot of search on this, and the solutions i found would be:

1. having it run in a subshell
2. `set +m` can deal with `Done` message only.
3. suppress it explicitly: `{ cmd & } 2>/dev/null` which won't suppress `Done` and it suppresses all my `stderr` too.

but in my condition, they don't work quite fine since i want extra parallelism. the framework should be:

```
cmd1 &>>log &
cmd2 &>>log &
wait
cat file &
cat file2 >&2 &
wait
```

if i put things into subshells, output is suppressed, but `wait` won't block the program.

the rest two options doesn't work as i've stated.

the worst is i am expecting something will be output to `stderr`. so i am looking for a way to totally suppress these reporting things or any other work around that you can come up with.

Comment: `set +m` will disable the `Done` line (and missed lines shouldn't show when you re-enable monitoring I don't think) but it doesn't seem to disable the pid line.

Comment: @EtanReisner no. so that's why i am asking. doing it in subshell still needs `&`. have no idea how to get around with it.

Comment: @EtanReisner ok. it seems the `Done` message didn't come back. it did before, i think it's because i tested it with `sleep`.

Comment: I guess monitoring is a background-task-finished check and not a background-sending-time task. I hadn't really thought about that distinction before now.

Comment: The fact that the pid message goes to standard error complicates things if you want stderr from the command itself.

Comment: @EtanReisner i know. but i do need it. it's very said we have only two channels to the screen.

Comment: You can create as many ways to display to the screen as you want if that's all you need. You can write directly to the screen as well if you really wanted to. You could send stderr from the script/etc. to a process that filters out the messages you don't want too if you don't mind the cost associated with that.

Comment: @EtanReisner oh sorry i kind of misled you a little bit. i am not just targeting the screen. i am expecting the output can go `stdout` and `stderr` such that the subsequence command can capture it as it looks like. so basically i want to find a way such that corresponding file descriptors can be preserved.

Comment: always somebody downvotes people's question without leaving any messages.

Comment: Better answers [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097761/is-there-a-way-to-make-bash-job-control-quiet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very ugly but it *looks* like it works in a quick test.

```
set +m
{ { sleep 2; echo stdout; echo stderr >&2; } 2>&3- & } 3>&2 2>/dev/null
```

Create fd 3 as a copy of fd 2 then redirect fd 2 to `/dev/null` (to suppress the background id/pid message).

Then, for the backgrounded command list, move fd 3 back to fd 2 so things that try to use it go where you wanted them to.

My first attempt had the fd 3 mv in the outer brace command list but that didn't suppress the id/pid message correctly (I guess that happened too quickly or something).

Comment: yeah. came up with that too. it seems there are really no too many options left in bash

Comment: btw, what about `set -m`? will it reset automatically in parent shell?

Comment: No, you'd need to reset that after the `wait` if you want it in general but just not for these bits.