# Can not get access to stdout of background process (Ubuntu)

Tags: shell, ubuntu

When I start some background process in the shell, for example:

```
geth --maxpeers 0 --rpc &
```

It returns something like:

```
[1] 1859
```

...without any out stream of this process. I do not understand what is it? And how can I get `stdout` of `geth`?  There is information in documentation that `stdout` of background process is displayed in shell by default.

My shell is running in remote Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 2):

The "&" directs the shell to run the command in the background. It uses the fork system call to create a sub-shell and run the job asynchronously.

The stdout and stderr should still be printed to the screen.

If you do not want to see any output on the screen, redirect both stdout and stderr to a file by:

```
geth --maxpeers 0 --rpc > logfile 2>&1 &
```

Comment: ++, but it's worth noting that this only silences (redirects) the _command's_ output, but not the shell's job-control message.

Comment: Why stdout of a background process is  **not** associated with terminal window by default? In my case it must be set directly: `geth --rpc >&1 &`

Comment: @Mergasov: You say you're running the shell _remotely_: what software are you using? Using `ssh` shouldn't be a problem. Is there anything special about how `geth` writes output? Do other commands that produce stdout output act the same? At first glance, `>&1` looks like a no-op. Please add any clarifications _directly to your question_.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first part of your question:

> ...without any out stream of this process. I do not understand what is
>   it?

This is part of the *command execution environment* (part of the shell itself) and is not the result of your script. (it is how the shell handles backgrounding your script, and keeping track of the process to allow *pause* and *resume* of jobs).

If you look at `man bash` under `JOB CONTROL`, it explains what you are seeing in detail, e.g.

> The shell associates a job with each pipeline. It keeps a table 
>    of currently executing jobs, which may be listed with the `jobs` 
>    command. When bash starts a job asynchronously (in the background),
>    it prints a line that looks like:
>
> ```
>     [1] 25647
> ```

Answer (score 1):

> I do not understand what is it? `[1] 1859`

It is the **output from Bash's *job* feature**, which enables managing background processes (jobs), and it contains information about the job just started, printed to stderr:

- `1` is the **job ID** (which, prefixed with `%`, can be used with builtins such as `kill` and `wait`)
- `25647` is the **PID** (process ID) of the background process.

Read more in the `JOB CONTROL` section of `man bash`.

> how can I get stdout of `geth`? There is information in documentation that stdout of background process is displayed in shell by default.

Indeed, **background jobs by default print their output to the current shell's stdout and stderr streams**, but note that they do so *asynchronously* - that is, output from background jobs will appear as it is produced (potentially buffered), interleaved with output sent directly to the current shell, which can be disruptive.

**You can apply redirections as usual to a background command** in order to capture its output in file(s), as demonstrated in [user3589054's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40829403/45375), but note that doing so will not silence the *job-control message* (`[1] 1859` in the example above).

If you want to **silence the job-control message on creation**, use:

```
{ geth --maxpeers 0 --rpc & } 2>/dev/null
```

To silence the entire life cycle of a job, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38278291/45375) of mine.