# Suppress output from & in Linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, output

I've seen answers from multiple posts talking about sending output from a program to `/dev/null` and also suppressing error output by using `2>&1`, but how can I use all of these AND suppress output from sending it to a background process by typing the `&` symbol?

Example:

```
feh "image.jpg" & >/dev/null 2>&1
```

still returns "[#] {PID}" (with the numbers filled in of course). If anyone can help me out that would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Manjaro Linux and my kernel version is `5.11.10-1-MANJARO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once `&` is encountered, the first command (`feh "image.jpg"`) is sent to the background, then separately the shell executes `>/dev/null 2>&1`, which executed alone like this does nothing. You need to set up the output pipes/redirection before sending the process to background:

`feh "image.jpg" > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo "Second command"`

Note that `> /dev/null` is the same as `1> /dev/null` which means you can do `>/dev/null 2>/dev/null` or `1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null` to get the same effect.

For the job termination output, you can [wrap your command in parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11111042/13020139) like this:

`(feh "image.jpg" > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo "Second command" )`

As mentioned in the linked post, be aware that this will make you lose control of the process that you send to back with `&`.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, but my issue still remains: The output from "&" (aka "[1] 76571", as an example) still remains. My question is how to get of this line.