# Terminate tcpdump in script and continue executing next command

Tags: bash, tcpdump, terminate, bash-trap

I am trying to create a script in which I have:

```
tcpdump (options) | fgrep (options) > file
```

After I terminate tcpdump with CTRL+C I want these commands to execute:

```
sed (options) file | awk (options)
wait
rm file
```

The first part is getting done but after I press CTRL+C I get thrown to the prompt. I tried with wait, with trap SIGINT, same problem.

Now to get the obvious out of the way: why not simply pipe everything without dumping intermediary unfiltered output to a temporary file? Well I tried that but it seems the information is getting lost in my screen output (busy server, don't know) and I found that breaking the commands like this will allow me to have full output.

**UPDATE**:
Based on the answers I got below, I tried doing it like this, it seemed to be the safest way to make it work:

```
function1 ()
{
tcpdump (options) | fgrep (options) > file
trap "function2" SIGINT SIGTERM
}

function2 ()
{
sed (options) file | awk (options)
wait
rm -i file
}
```

It doesn't work. "file" is generated but its content doesn't seem to be read and filtered by the sed | awk syntax after I do CTRL+C and it is not even being deleted by rm command so this is further proof that the secondary, trapped function is not being executed. I don't understand this behavior, am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE 2:** The only way I could get it to work properly was like this:

```
set -m

tcpdump (options) | fgrep (options) > filename &

trap "kill -9 $!" SIGINT

sed (options) filename | mawk (options)

\rm filename
```

But I could not suppress the output from killing the background process, tried all the solutions I could find:
[Running bash commands in the background without printing job and process ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686989/running-bash-commands-in-the-background-without-printing-job-and-process-ids) - this one makes my trap non-functional; [With Bash Scripting, how can I suppress all output from a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617182/with-bash-scripting-how-can-i-suppress-all-output-from-a-command) - all the variants from here do not work, I still get output no matter what I do. Tried defining the $! with another variable, tried all variants for /dev/null, tried placing it within the trap command, no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it work for you to start the `tcpdump` command in the background and terminate it after a fixed amount of time? E.g. run

```
(tcpdump (options) | fgrep (options) > file) &
```

then get the pid of the process and wait some time,

```
pid=$! 
sleep 60
```

and finally kill the command and parse the output

```
kill -9 $pid
sed (options) file | awk (options)
rm file
```

**Update**

If you really want `Ctrl-P` to stop `tcpdump`, `trap` is the way to go. However, after the trapped command is executed, you will always end up at the shell! So the behavior you described is actually what `trap` is supposed to do.

Thus you could write your `trap` command as

```
trap "{ sed (options) file | awk (options); rm file; }" SIGINT SIGTERM
```

and it should perform all the post-processing on interrupt. If you have more than these simple commands, it might make more sense to put all post-processing commands in a new script or function, e.g.

```
exec_on_interrupt() {
  sed (options) file | awk (options)
  rm file
  # other stuff...
}

trap "exec_on_interrupt" SIGINT SIGTERM
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to specify a defined amount of time for what I want to use this. Terminating tcpdump must be done by user via CTRL+C.

Comment: Running in the background is not a bad idea... maybe you can do as @Michael suggests and have your bash script wait for some user input when you're ready to kill it ("Press q when you want tcpdump to stop...", and just sit there waiting). Capturing such input seems easier than forcing CTRL+C to mean "kill the tcpdump process but not this script".

Comment: I updated my question, unfortunately the provided solution doesn't seem to work as intended on my machine and I don't understand why.

Comment: I finally got it working by using the first proposed solution and defined a key that when pressed will execute the kill -9 command for the PID. I still would have liked to use CTRL+C to terminate tcpdump.