# Get pid of long running process started in Bash script

Tags: bash

I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/my-path/to/long-running-process/start-server
```

This starts up a JVM server which is supposed to keep working after the bash script terminates. How can I get the PID of the JVM process from within the same bash script so I can write it to a file in case I need to kill it later?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the process id of command executed in bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532233/how-to-get-the-process-id-of-command-executed-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) covers this under [Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters):

```
#!/bin/bash

/my-path/to/long-running-process/start-server &

echo $! > /path/to/your/pid/file.pid
```

Comment: Thanks - If a script that is called from inside a script itself starts a process is it possible to have the PID filter down to the original script?