# Execute process in background, without printing "Done", and get PID

Tags: bash

This seems like a pretty trivial thing to do, but I'm very stuck.

To execute something in the background, use `&`:

```
>>> sleep 5 &
[1] 21763
>>> #hit enter
[1]+  Done                    sleep 5
```

But having a bashrc-sourced background script output job information is pretty frustrating, so you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686989/running-bash-commands-in-the-background-without-printing-job-and-process-ids) to fix it:

```
>>> (sleep 5 &)
```

OK, so now I want to get the PID of `sleep` for `wait` or `kill`. Unfortunately its running in a subshell so the typical `$!` method doesn't work:

```
>>> echo $!
21763
>>> (sleep 5 &)
>>> echo $!
21763 #hasn't changed
```

So I thought, maybe I could get the subshell to print its PID in this way:

```
>>> sleep 5 & echo $!
[1] 21803 #annoying job-start message (stderr)
21803 #from the echo
```

But now when I throw that in the subshell no matter how I try to capture stdout of the subshell, it appears to block until `sleep` has finished.

```
>>> pid=$(sleep 5 & echo $!)
```

**How can I run something in the background, get its PID and stop it from printing job information and "`Done`"?**

Comment: FYI, job control is turned off by default in scripts, so you shouldn't see the job number information printed in that scenario.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy As jm666 has correctly guessed, I'm sourcing this script and want to have it running in the background of my main shell. Will clarify in the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution A

When summoning the process, redirect the shell's stderr to `>/dev/null` for that summoning instance. We can do this by duplicating fd 2 so we could still use the duplicate fd for the process. We do all of these inside a block to make redirection temporary:

```
{ sleep 5 2>&3 & pid=$!; } 3>&2 2>/dev/null
```

Now to prevent the "Done" message from being shown later, we exclude the process from the job table and this is done with the `disown` command:

```
{ sleep 5 2>&3 & disown; pid=$!; } 3>&2 2>/dev/null
```

It's not necessary if job control is not enabled. Job control can be disabled with `set +m` or `shopt -u -o monitor`.

## Solution B

We can also use command substitution to summon the process. The only problem we had is that the process still hooks itself to the pipe created by `$()` that reads stdout but we can fix this by duplicating original stdout before it then using that file descriptor for the process:

```
{ pid=$( sleep 200s >&3 & echo $! ); } 3>&1
```

It may not be necessary if we redirect the process' output somewhere like `/dev/null`:

```
pid=$( sleep 200s >/dev/null & echo $! )
```

Similarly with process substitution:

```
{ read pid < <(sleep 200s >&3 & echo $!); } 3>&1
```

Some may say that redirection is not necessary for `process substitution` but the problem is that the process that may be accessing its `stdout` would die quickly. For example:

```
$ function x { for A in {1..100}; do echo "$A"; sleep 1s; done }
$ read pid < <(x & echo $!)
$ kill -s 0 "$pid" &>/dev/null && echo "Process active." || echo "Process died."
Process died.
$ read pid < <(x > /dev/null & echo $!)
$ kill -s 0 "$pid" &>/dev/null && echo "Process active." || echo "Process died."
Process active.
```

- Optionally you can just create a permanent duplicate fd with `exec 3>&1` so you can just have `pid=$( sleep 200s >&3 & echo $! )` on the next lines.

Comment: good point about preserving output. I particularly like this as the process doesn't need to run in a subshell too. however, as @jm666 points out I lose job control `-bash: fg: no job control`. for the moment I still prefer the subshell method

Answer (score 4):

You can use `read` bulletin to capture output:

```
read -r pid < <(sleep 10 & echo $!)
```

Then:

```
ps -p $pid
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
78541 ttys001    0:00.00 sleep 10
```

Comment: very interesting. could you explain why I need to use `read`? Also, I should have realized this would happen earlier: `bash: wait: pid 22108 is not a child of this shell`.

Comment: `wait` won't work because sleep is executed in a sub shell and background process id is not sub process of current shell process.

Comment: @jozxyqk, `read` reads a single line and immediately returns without blocking further, whereas typical command substitution continues to try to read until the subprocess's stdout is closed.

Answer (score 3):

The `set +m` disable monitor mode in bash. In other words it rid off the annnoying `Done` message.
To enable again, use `set -m`.

eg:

```
$ set +m
$ (sleep 5; echo some) &
[1] 23545 #still prints the job number

        #after 5 secs
some
$  #no Done message...
```

Comment: well this just removes all the complexity doesn't it. cheers!

Comment: @jozxyqk not really because it disables job control, so you didn;t get notifications about when background job waiting for input, can't list jobs and so on... Not recommented to use it in `.bashrc` only occasionally when you really know what you doing. ;)

Comment: @jozxyqk :) ;) sure. The set is powerful. See the man here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
pid=$((sleep 5 & echo $!) | sed 1q)
```

Comment: indeed, this works. can you explain why `sed 1q` behaves differently to say `cat`?

Comment: `sed 1q` read the first line and then exits immediately. If a member in a pipe terminates (here `sed`), then all others (here `$(...)`) are also terminated and only then can the output assigned to $pid. Only `sleep 5` continues in background.

Comment: If this kind of solution (which blocks stdout) is accepted, then you wouldn't need sed anymore. [See my solution.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24844613/445221)

Comment: Does this have any advantage over @anubhava's approach? Strikes me as a less efficient way of doing the same thing (on account of the overhead of using `sed`, vs the in-process builtin `read`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy One obvious thing is that it doesn't require named pipes when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I found a great way, no need sub-shell, will keep the parent-child relationship.
Since: `[1] 21763` and `[1]+  Done sleep 5` are all stderr, which is `&2`.
We can redirect `&2` to `/dev/null`, here is code:

```
exec 7>&2 2>/dev/null # Here backup 2 to 7, and redirect 2 to /dev/null
sleep 5
wait
exec 2>&7 7>&- # here restore 7 to 2, and delete 7.
```

See: [Using exec](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17974.html)