# How to unbuffer stdout of legacy running binary without stdbuf and similar tools

Tags: bash, pipe, buffer, petalinux

I want to monitor the realtime output of a program that I will start. I am trying to do this by redirecting the output of the program to a pipe and then reading the pipe from a monitoring script.

```
./program >> apipe
```

then from the monitoring script

```
cat apipe
```

However due to the buffer in >> there is no output. Anyway I can disable this buffer? I am running on a barebones embedded system (petalinux) so I don't have access to unbuffer, script, or stdbuf to help me out.

I have tried the scripts on another platform where unbuffer is available it works as I expect.

Any way I can configure this buffer, or use another binary to redirect?

Edit: I do not have access to the source code of the command I am trying to run. It is a legacy binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have access to `stdbuf`, you might as well simulate it and **unbuffer the `stdout` manually** with `gdb` (assuming obviously you have access to `gdb`).

Let's take a look at how `stdbuf` actually operates. The [`stdbuf`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/stdbuf.c) GNU coreutils command basically only injects `libstdbuf` in the user program by setting `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable. (Irrelevant, but for the record, options are passed via `_STDBUF_E`/`_STDBUF_I`/`_STDBUF_O` env vars.)

Then, when the [`libstdbuf`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/libstdbuf.c) is run, it calls [`setvbuf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html) libc function (which in turn executes the underlaying syscall) on appropriate file descriptors (`stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr`), with the appropriate mode (fully buffered, line buffered, or unbuffered).

Declaration for `setvbuf` is in `stdio.h`, available with `man 3 setvbuf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int setvbuf(FILE *stream, char *buf, int mode, size_t size);
```

Values for `mode` are: `_IONBF`, `_IOLBF`, `_IOFBF`, as defined in `stdio.h`. We are here only interested in the unbuffered mode: `_IONBF`. It has a value of `2` (you can check your `/usr/include/stdio.h`).

#### Unbuffer script

So, to unbuffer a `stdout` for some process, we just need to call:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)
```

We can easily do that with `gdb`. Let's make a script we can call, `unbuffer-stdout.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage: unbuffer-stdout.sh PID

gdb --pid "$1" -ex "call setvbuf(stdout, 0, 2, 0)" --batch
```

Then, we can call it like:

```
$ ./unbuffer-stdout.sh "$(pgrep -f my-program-name)"
```

(You'll probably need `sudo` to run it as `root`.)

#### Testing

We can use this simple Python program with buffered standard output (if not called with `-u`, and with unset `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`), `writer.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, time

while True:
    sys.stdout.write("output")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Run it with:

```
$ ./writer.py >/tmp/output &
$ tailf /tmp/output
```

and observe no output appears until we run:

```
$ sudo ./unbuffer-stdout.sh "$(pgrep -f writer.py)"
```

Comment: Wow, great answer, I was currently exploring doing this using GDB but my main concern is performance. This binary is fairly mission critical and we can't afford performance hits. Is this a valid concern?

Comment: Well, you need to do this only once. On my system the complete patching takes 30ms. I don't know if that's acceptable for your needs.