# Chicken-And-Egg-Situation: Function for running commands in the background

Tags: bash, function, redirect, detach

I fear this might be a duplicate, but I couldn't find a matching question.

I mostly work on the command line. If i.e. I want to simply open a pdf-file, I want to keep my actual commandline working and not being flooded with whatsoever output.

In general

`evince my_file.pdf </dev/null &>/dev/null &`

does the job...but typing that is not very convenient. So I tried to add a function:

```
function exec_in_background_silent() {
    "$@" </dev/null &>/dev/null &
}
```

That kind of works for the purpose to run the passed command detached...but calling it like this:

`exec_in_background_silent evince my_file.pdf`

Makes me loose my commandline again, because I think now it waits for the function itself to finish :(

It works perfectly fine, if I add another ampersand:

`exec_in_background_silent evince my_file.pdf &`

But: Is there a way to get rid of it?

(evince is maybe a bad example, because it isn't very talkative anyway...but there are others ;))

***Edit for more details:***

I'm running Ubuntu

```
echo "${BASH_VERSION}"
5.0.17(1)-release
```

1. After calling it the command line is locked
2. Pressing Enter get's me new empty lines
3. Pressing `[strg]+[c]` gives the following output and terminates evince

```
exec_in_background_silent evince my_file.pdf
[1] 12234







^C
[1]+  Fertig                   < /dev/null &> /dev/null
```

Comment: Strange! Your function works perfectly in my bash. Can we compare?

Comment: The function doesn't wait for the background command, it finishes immediately. So the main shell shouldn't delay when it waits for that.

Comment: Maybe executing "screen -d -m evince my_file.pdf"?

Comment: Added a few details above. @masterguru: The given screen command example behaves exactly the same way: It works fine if called directly, but breaks inside the function.

Comment: @roccobaroccoSC You're right. On another computer it works fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In manpage of bash, it says:

> When bash starts a job asynchronously (in the background), it prints a
> line that looks like:
>
> ```
> [1] 25647
> ```
>
> indicating that this job is job number 1 and that the process ID of the last process in the pipeline associated with this
> job is 25647. All of the processes in a single pipeline are members of
> the same job. Bash uses the job abstraction as the basis for job
> control.

And @Dimitre Radoulov said in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686989/running-bash-commands-in-the-background-without-printing-job-and-process-ids):

> you could supress that output by putting the call in a subshell:
>
> (echo "Hello I'm a background task" &)

So, in order to avoid the job number and process ID output line, you should change your function like this:

```
function exec_in_background_silent() {
    ("$@" </dev/null &>/dev/null &)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That indeed even suppresses the job-ids (which i didn't even mind so far). I'm curious if that solves the problem on my other machine...but as it even works better as expected on this one, I'll happily accept the answer :)