# Shell Script Spinner Shows the PID

Tags: bash, sh

I'm trying to fake show a spinner when I "need" to run a long running piece of code (ok, so, it isn't long running, but I want it to seem that it is to my end user...)

On Android 12+

So, I've got the following shell script:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

# the spinner function
spinner() { 
    # show the spinner
    (
        while :; do 
            for c in / - \\ \|; do 
                printf '%s\b' "$c"; 
                sleep 0.025; 
            done; 
        done
    )& 
    
    # sleep the length of time specified when calling this
    sleep $(($1-1)); 
    
    # backspace and kill the process
    { 
        printf '\b'; 
        kill $! && wait $!; 
    } 2>/dev/null 
}

# call it!
spinner 5
```

It shows my spinner for 5 seconds, but also displays the following: `[1] 17823` before it... (which appears to be the pid of this, so that last number always changes...)

Any ideas how I can get rid if that?

Comment: Look at [Running bash commands in the background without printing job and process ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686989/running-bash-commands-in-the-background-without-printing-job-and-process-ids).

Comment: @PierreFrançois The problem with that is it breaks the ability to get the PID with `$!`.

Comment: When I run your script I don't see that message. That message is only shown in shells with job control, it shouldn't happen in a script.

Comment: I also don't see the spinner, but that's because my terminal has an opaque cursor, and it covers up the spinner character. It would be better to do the backspace *before* printing the character instead of after.

Comment: @PierreFrançois can you elaborate on that in an answer please?  I did look through it, and and got it working with help from it.

Comment: Are you perhaps testing this by sourcing it into an interactive shell? Don't do that (unless interactive shells are part of the "real" target environment); use a noninteractive shell so job control is off.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I wouldn't need it in a non-interactive shell.  This is for a set of tweaks for android devices that must be run in an interactive shell :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a couple of changes, this worked for me :

```
#!/bin/sh

# the spinner function
spinner() { 
    # show the spinner
    {
        while :; do
            for c in / - \\ \|; do
                printf '%s\b' "$c";
                sleep 0.025; 
            done; 
        done &
    } 2>/dev/null
    
    # sleep the length of time specified when calling this
    sleep $(($1-1));
    
    # backspace and kill the process
    { 
        printf '\b'; 
        kill $! && wait $!; 
    } 2>/dev/null
}

# call it!
spinner 5
```

Comment: Perfect.  Works great. One tweak to one-line it, put a `;` after the first `2>/dev/null` :)